# How to use path-to-regexp (and react-router-4) to match all paths that's not starting with /auth?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router

I can't figure out how to use react-router-4 (and so path-to-regex) to match all path tha's not starting with /auth

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/^(?!\/?auth).+$/"  component={AppWelcome} />
    <Route path="/auth"  component={AppAuth} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch
```

With `/^(?!\/?auth).+$/` i get this error[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need a path for that. If you're inside a switch statement, only one route will be rendered. So if you make your auth route the first route, and then your catch anything route second you'll get your ```AppWelcome``` component for anything that doesn't match '/auth'. In either case, if you're trying to match any route that's not 'auth', you'll never hit your ```NoMatch``` route.

Comment: Have you tried using `exact` inside `<Route>` and you can place your '/auth/` in the last `<Route>`  if you are using `<Switch>`

Comment: If you want to use regexp—use it, not a string